# Move files from one folder to another C# Error File being used by another process

Tags: c#

I tired to copy files containing a particular string from one folder to another but it keeps giving me the error message System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file 'Z:\Upload\Text-File-1.txt' because it is being used by another process. Have tried a few things but nothing works. Not sure how to fix it.

```
using System;
using System.IO;


namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CheckandMoveFiles();

        }

    private static void CheckandMoveFiles()
    {
        //put filenames in array
        string[] sourcePath = Directory.GetFiles(@"Z:\Upload\");

        string targetPath = @"Z:\Upload\TextFiles\";

            try
            {
                    //Get each filepath and check for string
                foreach (string name in sourcePath)
                    {
                        string d = "Text";

                        if (name.Contains(d))
                        {
                            string fileName = name;
                            string sourceFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(sourcePath.ToString(), fileName);
                            string destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(targetPath, fileName);
                            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(sourceFile))
                            {

                                File.Copy(sourceFile, destFile, true);
                            }

                        }
                    }

            }
            catch (IOException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex); // Write error
            }
            Console.WriteLine("****************************DONE***************************************");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

}
}
```

Comment: Not sure if this is causing the error - but it doesn't seem unlikely: why on earth are you first opening the file for reading, and then try copying it through the file system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your problem is in the following lines:

```
string sourceFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(sourcePath.ToString(), fileName);
string destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(targetPath, fileName);
```

because `fileName` already contains the full path, and `sourcePath` is a string array, so `sourcePath.ToString()` would not yield the path you expect.
Instead try:

```
string sourceFile = fileName;
string destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(targetPath, System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fileName));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(sourceFile))
{
    File.Copy(sourceFile, destFile, true);
}
```

You're opening a `StreamReader` to read the `sourceFile`, and then you try to `File.Copy()` it? that's why you're getting the error

Lose the StreamReader, you don't need it

```
File.Copy(sourceFile, destFile, true);
```

Will do

Comment: I had it the other way and it did not work so tried the using statement to see if it would close my file after opening it. Have retried it and it has failed

Answer (score 0):

Should be like this:

```
 if (name.Contains(d))
                {
                    string fileName = name;
                    string sourceFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(sourcePath.ToString(), fileName);
                    string destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(targetPath, fileName);

                    File.Copy(sourceFile, destFile, true);


                }
```

[File.Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6cfw35a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) takes file path as parameter not the stream that points to the file.

Comment: Had it like this before and have retried it again but still get the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

Try This Friend...

```
public class SimpleFileCopy
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string fileName = "test.txt";
        string sourcePath = @"C:\Users\Public\TestFolder";
        string targetPath =  @"C:\Users\Public\TestFolder\SubDir";       
        string sourceFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(sourcePath, fileName);
        string destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(targetPath, fileName);       
        if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(targetPath))
        {
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(targetPath);
        }
        System.IO.File.Copy(sourceFile, destFile, true);
        if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(sourcePath))
        {
            string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(sourcePath);           
            foreach (string s in files)
            {               
                fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(s);
                destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(targetPath, fileName);
                System.IO.File.Copy(s, destFile, true);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Source path does not exist!");
        }       
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: this is really nice but my issue comes when I try and get the a number of files that contain a specific string. I managed to do a simple copy but it is when I added these conditions that things changed.